# MacOS Mojave, ISO images, and "no mountable file systems" error

Tags: linux, macos, iso-image, freebsd, disk-utility

I have a little Gigabyte BRIX that I'm trying to install Linux on. However, my Mac appears to be barfing on every ISO image I've downloaded. So far, I've tried Mint and Ubuntu (and even FreeBSD out of curiosity), and I've verified their checksums (so not corrupt), but so far, MacOS is balking at every one of them with "no mountable file systems."

So far, my attempts to drop one of these onto a thumbdrive so that I can actually install it on the BRIX has been a failure. And yes, I've tried Etcher, but so far have totally bricked two USB drives; Disk Utility's First Aid just immediately gave up (something about a partition problem).

Is this something new with Mojave? I never had this much trouble before with ISO images.

I've tried the various `hdiutil attach -noverify -nomount` tricks, but I still can't seem to do anything with an ISO image. And yeah, I've used `hdiutil convert` to mutate it into a DMG, but I still get "no mountable file systems."

Anyone? I've been banging my head against this for a week now.

Comment: Are the ISO's undamaged, their hashes match & you can mount/browse them?

Comment: The ISOs are undamaged, their checksums match . . . and no, I can't mount them at all.

Comment: @mcglk, did you figure it out?

Answer (score 10):

Was trying to mount a Ubuntu Server ISO image on MacOS Mojave and ran into this.

Found an answer that works on the Unix Stack Exchange:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298685/can-a-mac-mount-a-debian-install-cd

**Step 1. Attaching as a block device**

```
# the '-nomount' option avoids the 'mount failed' error
$ hdiutil attach -nomount debian-8.5.0-amd64-CD-1.iso 
/dev/disk2              Apple_partition_scheme          
/dev/disk2s1            Apple_partition_map             
/dev/disk2s2            Apple_HFS   

# verify disk is a block device (indicated by 'b' at line start)
$ ls -l /dev/disk2
br--r-----  1 amorphid  staff    1,   5 Jul 27 19:41 /dev/disk2
```

**Step 2. Mount the disk with cd9660 (aka ISO9660) file system**

```
# create mount point
$ mkdir -p /tmp/debian-installer

# mount the disk
$ mount -t cd9660 /dev/disk2 /tmp/debian-installer

# see da filez!
$ ls -l /tmp/debian-installer
total 2296
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    9468 Jun  4 09:24 README.html
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  185525 Jun  1 00:52 README.mirrors.html
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel  100349 Jun  1 00:52 README.mirrors.txt
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel     461 Jun  4 08:37 README.source
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel    6000 Jun  4 09:24 README.txt
-r--r--r--  1 root  wheel     146 Jun  4 08:37 autorun.inf
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    2048 Jun  4 08:37 boot
...
```

**Step 3. Unmount the disk**

```
# this will fail if the disk is being used
$ umount /dev/disk2
```

**Step 4. Detach the disk**

```
$ hdiutil detach /dev/disk2
"disk2" unmounted.
"disk2" ejected.
```

Comment: thanks man! the only workable solution I found so far. I had "no mountable file systems" error while mounting .dmg on Catalina. So funny, I have made a dmg image from cd disk  as it safer, but turns out you can't rely even on it.

Comment: I'm getting mount_cd9660: Invalid argument for the mount command